# Residue of $\frac{1}{(a+\cos z)^{2}}$, $a>1$

Tags: complex-analysis

The function $f(z)=\frac{1}{(a+\cos z)^{2}}$ has a pole at a point where the denominator vanishes, call it $\alpha$.  The residue of $f$ at $\alpha$ is $\lim_{z\rightarrow \alpha} \frac{d}{dz}^{n-1} \frac{(z-\alpha)^{n}}{(a+\cos z)^{2}}$ where $n$ is the order of the pole.  But when I try to compute this residue for any value of $n$ it becomes clear that the limit doesn't exist because there are always terms where the power of $a+\cos(z)$ in the denominator is larger than the power of $z-a$.  Naively, if you "push the limit through" (quotations becomes this doesn't make sense) and consider $\frac{(z-\alpha)^{2}}{(a+\cos z)^{2}}$ to be $\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dz}\cos z}$ then you get $\lim_{z\rightarrow \alpha} \frac{-2\cos z}{\sin z^{3}}$ which looks like the desired result.

I've been staring at this residue for a long time and it is clear to me that i've become blind to whatever the confusion is.  I don't need a long explanation, can someone please just tell me what the error is, simply put?

In conclusion: I believe the error I made was assuming that the limit for a pole of order two diverged when really it gives an the improper result of $\infty-\infty$.  This is would have been the ideal answer I was looking for, but I don't blame anyone for not going through the trouble of actually computing one of these poles, which is kind of a pain.  Thank you to Adam whose answer lead directly to this realization.

Comment: Why “two poles”? That function has infinitely many poles!

Comment: Right, I was thinking inside a certain contour.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos your comment assumes you know that the zeros in the denominator are actually poles.  Can you perhaps share this knowledge?  Are all the poles of order 2?  Something that's helpful?

Comment: Maple says the pole at $z=\pi-\arccos(a)$ is a double pole with residue $a/(1-a^2)^{3/2}$.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd Do you find my answer useful?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you for your solution, but I would like to know why, when I try to compute the above residue for a pole of order 2, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: My calculations give $\lim_{z\rightarrow \alpha} \frac{d}{dz} \frac{(z-a)^{2}}{(a+cosz)^{2}}=\lim_{z\rightarrow \alpha} \frac{2(z-a)}{(a+cosz)^{2}} + \frac{2(z-a)^{2}sinz}{(a+cosz)^{3}}$.

Comment: $z-a$ should of course be replaced with $z-\alpha$ above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actualy are missing a factor $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$  in the expression for residuum: $$ {\rm Res}_{z=\alpha} f(z) = \lim_{z\rightarrow\alpha} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \big((z-\alpha)^n f(z)\big)$$

Most importantly, note that in general $\alpha \neq a$. $\alpha$ is the position of the singualrity, that is, it's the point at which $$ a+\cos \alpha= 0$$ that is $\cos \alpha = -a$.

You can check that in general it will be a pole of second order (because of the square in the denominator), with exception of $a=\pm 1$ in which cases the pole turns out to be of fourth order.

For $a\ne\pm 1$ you have
$$ {\rm Res}_{z=\alpha} \frac{1}{(a+\cos z)^2} = \lim_{z\rightarrow\alpha} \frac{d}{dz} \frac{(z-\alpha)^2}{(a+\cos z)^2} = \lim_{z\rightarrow\alpha} \left(\frac{2(z-\alpha)}{(a+\cos z)^2}+(z-\alpha)^2\frac{2\sin z}{(a+\cos z)^3}\right) = \\ = \lim_{z\rightarrow\alpha} 2\frac{z-\alpha}{a+\cos z}\frac{(a+\cos z)+(z-\alpha)\sin z}{(a+\cos z)^2}  $$
Using the l'Hospital's rule:
$$ \lim_{z\rightarrow\alpha} \frac{z-\alpha}{a+\cos z} = \lim_{z\rightarrow\alpha} \frac{1}{-\sin z} = -\frac{1}{\sin\alpha}  $$ 
$$ \lim_{z\rightarrow\alpha} \frac{(a+\cos z)+(z-\alpha)\sin z}{(a+\cos z)^2} =  \lim_{z\rightarrow\alpha}  \frac{(z-\alpha)\cos z}{-2(a+\cos z)\sin z} = \\ = \lim_{z\rightarrow\alpha} \frac{z-\alpha}{a+\cos z} \lim_{z\rightarrow\alpha}  \frac{\cos z}{-2\sin z} = \frac{\cos \alpha}{2\sin^2 \alpha}$$
In total:
$$ {\rm Res}_{z=\alpha} \frac{1}{(a+\cos z)^2} = -\frac{\cos \alpha}{\sin^3 \alpha} = \pm \frac{a}{(1-a^2)^\frac32}$$
where the sign depends on whether $\sin \alpha = +\sqrt{1-a^2}$ or $\sin \alpha = -\sqrt{1-a^2} $.

I'll leave the case $a=\pm 1$ to you.

Comment: But a constant shouldn't affect whether or not the limit converges, right?

Comment: Furthermore, when $n=2$, $(n-1)!=1$ so it doesn't matter anyways.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd If you're talking about the factor $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ then yes, it does not affect the convergence, but it may afftct the final value when you calculate the residuum at pole of order greater than 2 (that is $a=\pm1$). What affects the convergence is whether you multiply incorrectly by $(z-a)^2$ or correctly by $(z-\alpha)^2$.

Comment: Oh, am I summing two limits, one which goes to $\infty$ and one which goes to $-\infty$?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd I believe it may be the case, if you try to calculate $$ \lim{z\rightarrow\alpha} \left( \frac{2(z-\alpha)}{(a+\cos z)^2} +\frac{(z-\alpha)^2 \sin z}{(a+\cos z)^3}\right) $$ by writing it as a sum of two limits you indeed get $+\infty - \infty$. But that only means that you cannot separate it like this, not that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, I see now.

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor series of $\bigl(a+\cos(z)\bigr)^2$ centered at $\alpha$ is\begin{multline}\left(a^2+2 a \cos (\alpha )+\cos ^2(\alpha )\right)+(z-\alpha ) (-2 a\sin (\alpha )-2 \sin (\alpha ) \cos (\alpha ))+\\+(z-\alpha )^2 \left(-a \cos (\alpha )+\sin ^2(\alpha )-\cos ^2(\alpha )\right)+\frac{1}{3}(z-\alpha )^3 (a \sin (\alpha )+4 \sin (\alpha ) \cos (\alpha))+\\+O\left((z-\alpha )^4\right)\end{multline}and so if, in particular, $\alpha$ is such that $\cos(\alpha)=-a$, that series is$$\left(1-a^2\right) \left(z-\alpha\right)^2-a \sqrt{1-a^2}\left(z-\alpha\right)^3+O\left((z-\alpha )^4\right).$$So, if we have$$\frac1{\bigl(a+\cos(z)\bigr)^2}=\frac{b_{-2}}{(z-\alpha)^2}+\frac{b_{-1}}{z-\alpha}+b_0+\cdots,$$then we have$$1=b_{-2}(1-a^2)+\left(b_{-1}(1-a^2)-b_{-2}a\sqrt{1-a^2}\right)(z-\alpha)+O\bigl((z-\alpha)^2\bigr).$$It is easy to deduce from this that $b_{-2}=\frac1{1-a^2}$ and that$$\operatorname{res}_{z=\alpha}\frac1{\bigl(a+\cos(z)\bigr)^2}=b_{-1}=\frac{a}{\left(1-a^2\right)^{3/2}}.$$